# Replace href/add attribute in external page to be relevant to current url

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a navigation html that gets loaded into every page across a site, it looks like this:

```
<div id="links-row">
    <ul class="cssmenu">
        <li class="home"><a title="Home" href="../"></a></li>
        <li class="sale"><a title="Sale" href="../sale"></a></li>
        <li class="news"><a title="News" href="../news">
        <li class="contact"><a title="Contact" href="../contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It gets loaded into pages with js:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#navigation").load("../_nav.html");
});
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
</div>
```

I can highlight links individually by setting the class of `<a>` to "Selected". What I would like to do is add the class attribute and change the href to "#" instead of the existing url based on the current page. I know I can get the current page name via js with:

```
path = window.location.pathname;
page = path.replace(/\//g,"");
```

My question is; how can I search the loaded page to find the relevant link and then change that specific links url href and set it's class

Comment: you can use the [complete](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to select the element by it's href, you can craft a jQuery slector like this `$('a[href="../' + page + ']')` and use `addClass` on that element.

Comment: and I might consider giving the menu items a class, for example `menu-item`, which would allow you to select the menu items easily, then simply `$(".menu-item a").attr("href", "#");` inside the callback that @gaetanoM mentioned. Or if you can't, use `$(".cssmenu li a").attr("href", "#");` to render the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input here's the result.

```
$(function(){
    path = window.location.pathname;
    page = path.replace(/\//g,"");
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("../_nav.html", function() {
        $('a[href="../' + page + '"]').addClass("Selected").attr("href", "#")
    });
});
```